# postgresql installation : initdb data directory not empty?

Tags: postgresql, installation

I am trying to create the postgresql database.

When I install PostgreSQL, I gave this command:

```
sudo yum install postgresql postgresql-server
```

and later I modified the config file:

```
sudo vim /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf
```

and modified as

```
local   all         all                               trust
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          trust
host    all         all         ::1/128               trust
host    all         all         0.0.0.0/0             md5
```

While I am trying to startup the postgresql service:

```
sudo service postgresql initdb

> Data directory is not empty!                               [FAILED]

sudo chkconfig postgresql on

sudo service postgresql start

Starting postgresql service:                               [  OK  ]
```

What is caused these errors and how do I fix them?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Initdb should only be run once. It will create the directory where you'll keep the config files and (usually) the actual database. You've obviously already done that already; otherwrise there wouldn't be any pg_hba.conf for you to edit.

So, just don't run `postgresql initdb` again, unless you are doing a complete reinstall.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. i run it twice... you mean the its not the problem in installation..

Comment: I mean that there is no problem with your installation, at least not any that you've shown. The only thing that is failing is doing initdb more than once, and that **should** fail - everything else shows as OK. If there's any other problem, it would help if you could describe it.

Comment: Thank you very much.. then its not a problem.. if i face a problem i will let you know..

Answer (score 19):

From [here](https://gist.github.com/kennwhite/2a3227165b14eca73b99):

If you're completely wiping & reinstalling a Postgres DB, when running `initdb` like:

`service postgresql-9.2 initdb -E 'UTF8' --pgdata="/foo/bar/"`

you can encounter this service error:

> Data directory is not empty! [FAILED]

To fix it (and this is the nuclear option -- all db data is wiped!)

**On Amazon Linux (2014-x):**

`rm -rf /var/lib/pgsql9/data`

**On CentOS (6.x)**

`rm -rf /var/lib/pgsql/9.2/data`

Now try the `initdb` command again and it should work this time:

`service postgresql-9.2 initdb`

Answer (score 5):

On systemd based systems like RHEL/CentOS 7 and Fedora the procedure for running initdb is somewhat different. This is no longer done by the init scripts (which no longer exist), and the new procedure is much closer to [the upstream instructions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/creating-cluster.html).

You must first `su` to the `postgres` user, and then run `initdb` or `pg_ctl initdb`. It's not necessary to provide a data directory if you are using a Red Hat build as its default automatically chooses the default data directory `/var/lib/pgsql`.

For example:

```
# su - postgres
$ pg_ctl initdb
$ exit
#
```

Of course, you only do this once, on first installation, to set up the initial data directory. You would not do it again unless you were creating a completely new installation or restoring from a disaster.

Comment: Hi, "you only do this once", did you mean run `pg_ctl initdb` only once whatsoever the options are followed, or did you mean that  one can run both `pg_ctl initdb` and `pg_ctl initdb -D /some/custom/dir` as long as the command point to a new `data_directory`?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, using PostgreSQL 9.3 on CentOS 6.

I deleted the /var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data folder, then re-ran the command

```
sudo service postgresql-9.3 initdb
```

... which successfully initialised the db service again.